# Autorun for PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-registry, powershell, regedit

I have created some aliases (`doskey`), saved them to a file and added `AutoRun` value (pointing that file) for `cmd.exe` at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

I would like to do the same with **PowerShell**. Is there any registry value for PowerShell which points to commands that will be run each time I start PowerShell?

Comment: I hate using doskey.  I find that just putting those aliases in my script (as function)s works better.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You would set up a profile. All commands in the profile are executed every time you start a PowerShell session. There are different profiles for user, machine, etc. As described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> #### Understanding the Profiles
>
> You can have four different profiles in Windows PowerShell. The profiles are listed in load order. The most specific profiles have precedence over less specific profiles where they apply.
>
> - **`%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`**
>     This profile applies to all users and all shells.
> - **`%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`**
>     This profile applies to all users, but only to the Microsoft.PowerShell shell.
> - **`%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`**
>     This profile applies only to the current user, but affects all shells.
> - **`%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`**
>     This profile applies only to the current user and the Microsoft.PowerShell shell.

Comment: `notepad $profile`

Comment: if you have no $profile, see how to create one here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461033.aspx

Comment: For current user the profile is `%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`